# Turning my current website configuration into a wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

My searches for this keep turning up "How to make a wp theme from scratch" which is not what I want. I made a website using the theme Scrawl, but I made a bunch of modifications. I would like to turn this into a theme so I can use it to make other sites without having to do much of the work again. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theme is simply the skin of the website. The configuration of the site, in broad sense of the word, is stored in the database and config files. If you want to transfer that, you can export the configuration settings from one site and import it in the other.

If you've only made modifications within the theme folder, you can simply .zip that folder and import the theme somewhere else.

Comment: Unfortunately when we try to import, it keeps failing. It would be convenient to turn it into a theme. Are you saying it's not an option?

Comment: Which type of configuration are you talking about specifically?

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: CSS, functions.php and also the positioning of elements in the page.

Comment: Fortunately, these should all be inside of your theme's folder. See the last bit of my answer, you can zip it and import it somewhere else.